# Proceed to check out not working - magento

Tags: magento, url, checkout, magento-1.8

When I click proceed to check out, am getting the error,

```
The requested URL /customer/account/login/ was not found on this server.
```

But when I manually modify the url like below,

```
mydomain.com/index.php/customer/account/login
```

It is working correctly.

Or  even when I click the `Login` link in home page it loads to the correct url with index.php

I have tried turning url rewrites on and off. Where am I going wrong.

I am using magento version 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Enable apache rewrite module on your server and restart it.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow below step

then use the following steps

1) Login to admin section by using the URL

```
http://domain.com/index.php/admin
```

2) then go to `System >>  Configuration >>Web >> Search Engines Optimization`
Use Web Server Rewrites : YES

3) Go to `System >>  Configuration >>Web >>Secure`
Use secure URL Frontend: YES

4)Then create the .htaccess file under your the magento installed folder.
If the magento installed under document root ( /home/username/public_html) then add follogig rules into `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and If the magento installed under /shop or directory then add the following rules into ” /home/username/public_html/shop/.htaccess ” file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: It didn't work. Now all my pages except my homepage are showing the error.

Comment: did you clear your cache. ? and sure you are followed all step correctly ? it should work. one more important thing is your server configuration enable rewrite module

Comment: Yes I did clear my cache and followed all the steps. When I give the following `sudo a2enmod rewrite`. I got the message `Module rewrite already enabled`.

Comment: Yes , I undid all the changes.

Comment: pls clear cache again and check with direct link to login page

Comment: As I said direct link to login page is working. I am having problem only When I click proceed to checkout without logging in.

Comment: but i think problem is only with your rewrite :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem reside in your url settings. Try below configuration

=> Log in into admin and go to `system -> configuration`

=> Select appropriate `configuration scope` for your site from top-left dropdown option.

=> Now go to `secure` section and set the `Base Link Url` as `https://yourdomain.com/index.php`.

Suppose your base url in secure section be `https://localhost/magento` then you need to set `Base Link Url` to `https://localhost/magento/index.php`.

=> Clear cache.

Try again